# How to total a field in a map?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm struggling to find how to get the total of an array returned from an API call. I'm using Next.js

```js
{positions.map(position => {
  return (
    <List
      title={position.title}
      slug={position.slug}
      quantity={position.quantity}
      position={position.position}
      price={position.transactionPrice}
      fees={position.fees}
      code={position.assetType.code}
      assetName={position.assetType.name}
      assetType={position.assetType.__typename}
    />
  );
})}
```

I want to add all of some a fields (i.e. fees) together to display above the list so it shows the total fees for all of the entries. I've already been told this isn't possible to do in the GraphQL API call, so how do I do this in Next.js / React?

I think I need to use the reduce array function but I don't know how to fit it into the code or what syntax? Would it come before return()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total by using reduce:

```js
const totalFees = positions.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.fees, 0);
```

And you can add that into your JSX however you'd like:

```
<div>Total fees: {totalFees}</div>
```

Comment: So simple and I just couldn't see it. Feel like an idiot! Thanks so much for that.